# @angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, angular-material

With Angular 8, While building the app, we encounter the following error:

```
app/modules/admin-module/pages/editor/editor.component.ts:6:27 - error TS2306: 
File ...node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**update: please check the answer of Jeff Gilliland below for updated solution**

Seems like as [this thread says](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503) a breaking change was issued:

> Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use
>   the individual secondary entry-points, such as
>   @angular/material/button.

**Update**: can confirm, this was the issue. After downgrading `@angular/material@9.0...` to  `@angular/material@7.3.2` we could solve this temporarily. Guess we need to update the project for a long term solution.

Comment: after doing the downgrade, do the `ng update @angular/material`, it will migrate and update all the imports for you :)

Answer (score 250):

After upgrading to Angular 9 (released today), I ran into this issue as well and found that they made the breaking change mentioned [in the answer](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/17503). I can't find a reason for why they made this change.

I have a material.module.ts file that I import / export all the material components (not the most efficient, but useful for quick development). I went through and updated all my imports to the individual material folders, although an index.ts barrel might be better. Again, not sure why they made this change, but I'm guessing it has to do with tree-shaking efficiencies.

Including my material.module.ts below in case it helps anyone, it's inspired off other material modules I've found:

**NOTE**: As other blog posts have mentioned and from my personal experience, be careful when using a shared module like below. I have 5~ different feature modules (lazy loaded) in my app that I imported my material module into. Out of curiosity, I stopped using the shared module and instead only imported the individual material components each feature module needed. This reduced my bundle size quite a bit, almost a 200kb reduction. I assumed that the build optimization process would properly drop any component not used by my modules, but it doesn't seem to be the case...

```js
// material.module.ts
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import { MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        MatNativeDateModule
    ],
    exports: [
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        MatNativeDateModule
    ],
    providers: [     
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
    constructor(public matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry) {
        // matIconRegistry.registerFontClassAlias('fontawesome', 'fa');
    }

    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<MaterialModule> {
        return {
            ngModule: MaterialModule,
            providers: [MatIconRegistry]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: I had same problem after upgrading angular 8 to 9. Your solution worked for me. This should be accepted answer in my opinion because it actually provides a solution for the upgraded version. Downgrading the version 9 back to 8 because of these errors should not be seen as the accepted solution to the problem. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: the following all come from material/core not angular/core (I guess):
import { MAT_LABEL_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

Comment: Good catch, in my haste I had put MatNativeDateModule in the wrong import :), fixed it in the answer

Comment: Yup, excellent answer, thanks.  One question: when they make crucial changes like this, why are the side-effects (like this "'index.d.ts' is not a module" error, when using Angular 9) so hopeless ?!!  Is that error meant to mean something to us developers ?

Comment: @MikeGledhill like many things in development, many things are esoteric. They should implement a solution that gives a deprecation warning or a more specific error message so you know how to fix it. The only other way that you would know how to fix this is if you have experience working with Typescript & Angular, and you know what the likely issue is when you see an error with a ".d.ts" file type. That knowledge usually comes from hours of frustration...there needs to be a better way of sharing this "domain knowledge" with others!

Comment: Google didn't provide a tool to automate this upgrade? Developers have to do this manually?

Comment: Thanks for the ready made import. Angular 9 upgrade with breaking changes. I hope this was automated as well.

Comment: Thanks, I adapted your solution by creating an alias path with all the import needed, have a good day!!

Comment: Using this solution  I am not able to import these two MatTabsModule and MatTreeModule

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it explains the exact cause and solution.

Comment: Note for Angular 10 you'll need to change the forRoot line to `static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders<MaterialModule> {`

Comment: @louisl thanks for the catch; updated the answer with the addition of the type!

Answer (score 101):

This can be solved by writing full path, for example if you want to include `MatDialogModule` follow:

**Prior to @angular/material 9.x.x**

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material";
//leading to error mentioned
```

**As per @angular/material 9.x.x**

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
//works fine
```

> Official change log breaking change reference: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#material-9

Comment: Worked for me as well.. Thanks.

Answer (score 40):

❌ DO NOT:

```js
// old code that breaks
import { MatDialogModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
```

✅ **DO:**

```js
// new code that works
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```

ℹ Because:

> Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use the individual secondary entry-points, such as @angular/material/button.

Comment: This worked for me. I have Angular 11.0.2 and Material 11.0.1 Thanks!

Answer (score 38):

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```

Comment: Welcome @Владимир on StackOverflow, It would be really helpful for reading if you add language code with ` ` ` (Without space i.e ` ` ` javascript) and close it. for more help please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Thank you. Keep contributing

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This code is very nice, but it would be nicer if you explain it. Otdelna, Ya ne smog paniat.

Comment: Thanks. Worked well for me!

Comment: From the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58594324/3705191): "Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use the individual secondary entry-points, such as @angular/material/button."

Comment: Thanks. Worked well for Angular 11.

Answer (score 24):

`@angular/material` has changed its folder structure. Now you need to use all the modules from their respective folders instead of just `material` folder

For example:

```
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material";
```

has now changed to

```
import { MatDialogModule } from "@angular/material/dialog";
```

You can check the following to find the correct path for your module

https://material.angular.io/components/categories

Just navigate to the API tab of required module and find the correct path like this 
[image: 1]

Comment: Worked for me :)

Comment: Excelent!
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

Answer (score 12):

Components cannot be further (From Angular 9) imported through general directory

you should add a specified component path like

```
import {} from '@angular/material';
```

`import {} from '@angular/material/input';`

Answer (score 5):

Just **update** @angular/material from **7** to **9**,

> npm uninstall @angular/material --save
>
> npm install @angular/material@^7.1.0 --save
>
> ng update @angular/material

Just wait and see Angular doing the Migration alone,

Hope it helps someone :)

Answer (score 2):

And also `ng update @angular/material` will update your code and fix all imports

Comment: This will only update package.json and package-lock.json. Will not change anything in our code

Comment: Just upgraded from 7 to 9, it did fix my imports, actually.

Answer (score 2):

First try to downgrade your angular version
using "ng add @angular/material7.3..0"
after that check if the error is gone
in my case it is gone
after that use this
ng update @angular/material
in case you are using angular 9 or 10
you have to write code like this
import {MatInputModule} from 'angular/material/input'
Hope it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Accepted Answer is correct, but it didn't fully work for me. I had to delete the package.lock file, re-run "npm install", and then close and reopen my visual studio. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

This issue still persists for Angular 11
to add commands

```
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
```

Solved it for now. But shortcuts for ng add @angular material should be available via Angular CLI

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with angular version 11. Downgrading angular/material version works

Answer (score -3):

I was also facing the same issue with the latest version of @angular/material i.e. "^9.2.3"
So I found out a solution of this. If you go to the folder of @angular/material inside node_modules, you can find a file naming index.d.ts, in that file paste the below code. With this change in the index file you will be able to import the modules using import statements from @angular/material directly. (P.S. If you face error in any of the below statements please comment that.)

```
export * from '@angular/material/core';
export * from '@angular/material/icon';
export * from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
export * from '@angular/material/badge';
export * from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
export * from '@angular/material/button';
export * from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
export * from '@angular/material/card';
export * from '@angular/material/checkbox';
export * from '@angular/material/chips';
export * from '@angular/material/stepper';
export * from '@angular/material/datepicker'
export * from '@angular/material/dialog';
export * from '@angular/material/divider';
export * from '@angular/material/esm2015';
export * from '@angular/material/form-field';
export * from '@angular/material/esm5';
export * from '@angular/material/expansion';
export * from '@angular/material/grid-list';
export * from '@angular/material/icon';
export * from '@angular/material/input';
export * from '@angular/material/list';
export * from '@angular/material/menu';
export * from '@angular/material/paginator';
export * from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
export * from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
export * from '@angular/material/radio';
export * from '@angular/material/stepper';
export * from '@angular/material/select';
export * from '@angular/material/sidenav';
export * from '@angular/material/slider';
export * from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
export * from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
export * from '@angular/material/sort';
export * from '@angular/material/table';
export * from '@angular/material/tabs';
export * from '@angular/material/toolbar';
export * from '@angular/material/tooltip';
export * from '@angular/material/tree';
```

Comment: You should never have to modify anything in node_modules.

Comment: If you do not want to do that then you will have to specifically mention the complete path of the module you want to import and in near future if we get an update where we can directly access the module then changing the import statements where ever you have mentioned it will be a tediuos task. Also if you import the module with complete path you will have a very long code, but if you change the index file you can import everything in a single statement.
Alternate option is:- you can create a .ts file somewhere outside the node_modules folder and paste this code there and import that file.

Answer (score -5):

Do `npm i -g @angular/material --save` to solve the problem

Comment: Consider adding more details and the usage of formatted codes