# Unable to import angular material

Tags: angular, import, mat-table

I'm getting the below error while trying to import angular material

```
  File 'c:/Workspace/phone-app/node_modules/@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)
```

Based on [@angular/material/index.d.ts' is not a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58594311/angular-material-index-d-ts-is-not-a-module) other threads, I have changed the import to

```
  import {MatPaginator, MatSort} from '@angular/material/MatSort';
```

However I still get this error :

```
        Cannot find module '@angular/material/MatSort'.ts(2307)
```

Here is my package.json file :

```
{
 "name": "phone-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
   "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/common": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/core": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/material": "^9.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/router": "~9.1.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"rxjs": "~6.5.4",
"tslib": "^1.10.0",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0",
"@angular/cli": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~4.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.3",
"ts-node": "~8.3.0",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~3.8.3"
 }
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json ? Have you installed it with npm ?

Comment: updated with pakcage.json , yes it was through npm

Comment: When you installed it through npm, did you directly run `npm install @angular/material`? When adding Angular/material to a project, it's [recommended](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) that you use `ng add @angular/material` .

If that still fails, you could try deleting your `node_modules` directory then reinstalling your dependencies with `npm install`.

Comment: no luck, tried deleting node_modules folder and reinstalling through npm install as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

and import the MatSort in the your module file.